# Change in Redux state object value not re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an object in my store that I can being updated when actions are dispatched. But I'm not seeing the updated value for `totalDevices` displayed on the page. It stays with the original render. What am I doing wrong?

**State**

```
{
  deviceCount: {
    'projectId:ed4b4e40-d4e2-4540-8359-c002526f2793': {
      totalDevices: 1,
      error: {}
    },
    'projectId:a6293167-ade2-4e22-98f0-70260fcee7f7': {
      totalDevices: 0,
      error: {}
    }
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
  const selectDeviceCount = useSelector((state) => state.deviceCount);
  const [currDeviceCount, setCurrDeviceCount] = useState(selectDeviceCount); // Using to display value of totalDevices for each item in object

  useEffect(() => {
    loadDeviceCountByProjectID({ projectId });
  }, [loadDeviceCountByProjectID]);

  useEffect(() => {  // Should this hook trigger a rerender on currDeviceCount? 
    setCurrDeviceCount(
      selectDeviceCount
    );
  }, [selectDeviceCount]);

  return (
    <ListItem
      className={variation === 'block' ? classes.listItem : ''}
      key={projectId}
      button
      component={Link}
      to={`/${organizationName}/${name}?per_page=10&page=1`}
    >
      <ListItemText>
            {name}
          </span>
        }
      />
      <ListItemAvatar className={classes.devicesAvatar}>
        <>
          <TabletAndroidIcon className={classes.deviceIcon} />
          <Typography variant="caption">
            // Conditional rendering to prevent errors when state is undefined on first load
            {selectDeviceCount.length > 0
              ? selectDeviceCount[`projectId:${projectId}`]?.totalDevices
              : 0}
          </Typography>
        </>
      </ListItemAvatar>
    </ListItem>
  );
```

Comment: `selectDeviceCount[0]` as mentioned below will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of hooks is fine, and your state should be changing. But you're measuring `selectDeviceCount.length` in your render, but `selectDeviceCount` is an object, and therefore has a length of 0. If you want to measure the number of keys inside the `selectDeviceCount` object, do `Object.keys(selectDeviceCount).length`

To mitigate `selectDeviceCount` being `undefined`, simply initialize the state to an empty object by doing `useState({})`

Below is the area where your code has the issue.

```js
<Typography variant="caption">
            // Conditional rendering to prevent errors when state is undefined on first load
            {Object.keys(selectDeviceCount).length > 0
              ? selectDeviceCount[`projectId:${projectId}`]?.totalDevices
              : 0}
          </Typography>
```